# Gridgain node disconnect

Tags: gridgain

We have grid gain setup across 5 nodes and very occasionally we see a network interruption happening across the nodes for 3 - 5 secs.During this period the nodes gets disconnected. The network gets back online after that duration but since the grid nodes got disconnected they cannot communicate. Is there any way to specify the grid nodes to have a ping or heartbeat to be happening > 5 secs so that they are never disconnected due to the network interruptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now GridGain will consider a node that is out for 5 seconds failed. I have filed an internal ticket to allow for a node to stay disconnected for a small while before it is considered failed. It should be fixed in a future release.

Having said that, it does seem rather unusual to have such break downs in your network.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy , yeah I agree its rather unsual but we are in a situation where we have to live with it and have the software take care of it. I was looking if there is a way to specify the timeout before the grid is considered disconnected.  Please let me know when the fix is released and meanwhile I will look for an alternate solution

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant, but GridGain also handles network split-brain situation. Please take a look at Network Segmentation documentation - http://entdoc.gridgain.org/latest/Network+Segmentation .

Comment: Also, would it be OK if nodes automatically restarted whenever grid gets disconnected? If yes, you can listen to node discovery events, and if the number of nodes in the grid goes below a certain amount, just automatically restart the node.

Comment: so you are saying the current node which gets disconnected from the rest of the nodes will receive some event ? I was assuming the other nodes will receive that a node has left and not the one that left ? In this case what do I enable so that the current node also knows about it ?

Comment: @Tadaka, in the described case both parts of the grid will receive events. Other n-1 nodes will receive event that one node failed, and that one disconnected node will receive event that other n-1 nodes failed. If you want to prevent this split-brain situation, you need to configure segmentation resolver, as Dmitriy mentioned. When segmentation resolver is configured, disconnected node will receive SEGMENTED event.